# Unable to open Pyspark Shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapr

I am running `./bin/pyspark` at to open the pyspark shell but I get the following error :

```
`py4j.protocol.PY4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java Server`
```

Searched about it a lot. Couldn't find a solution. 
How should I resolve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you running on windows machine or linux?

Comment: Also check if there have other applications used your java server port

Comment: @SharpLu Linux. And how do I check that ? How do I check what server port my Java is running on ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems like your Java issue

1. Please use commands to check your java process in your machine

   ps -ef|grep java
2. If doesn't works then please try to update your Java JDK to new.

   Download:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Have you checked the process of your system? ps -ef|grep java
   if there have other process used your Java